# JavaScript - callback - waiting for multiple functions to end

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, callback

I count the shortest path to the destination point from many  different origin points with google maps api. I decided to do it this way : (count for each pair of points than save results to array and than check at the end which  is best). But i have problem with callback - because as comments says array is always zero - because this code is performed before all requests to count the route length.

```
function foo(){
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var destination = new google.maps.LatLng(x,y);
var arrayOfRes= [];

for(var index in originPoints){
    var request = {
        origin:originPoints[index].marker.position,
        destination:destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                var res = {};
                res.length = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
                res.index = index;
                res.result = result;
                arrayOfRes.push(res);
            }
     });
}
  //here arrayOfRes.length is always 0
if(arrayOfRes.length>1)
{
    var bestResult = arrayOfRes[0];

    for(var i = 1; i < arrayOfRes.length; i++)
    {
        if(bestResult.length > arrayOfRes[i])
            bestResult = arrayOfRes[i];
    }

    console.log("Best is" + bestResult.length);
}
else if(arrayOfRes.length ==1)
{
    var bestResult = arrayOfRes[0];
}
 }
```

How to write function with callback so that it wait until all requessts are ended?

Comment: dude..common..you can crop the question..make it shorter,you definately get more replies when you ask something in a simpler way..

Comment: This question has been answered a lot of times. Do your best and try to find an answer.

Comment: You probably should make yourself familiar with promises, callbacks and asynchronous JavaScript in general.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige - promises could be used, but if they don't have a promises library handy, this can be solved with a simple check in the callback to see if this is the completion of the last request (as I've shown in my answer).

Comment: @jfriend00 yes using the callback of google maps directionsService is the best bet here, I agree. I just wanted to point out that it's an asynchronous request he is doing, but didn't make myself very clear.. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google requests like this are asynchronous so you have to write asynchronous code which means ONLY working with the returned data from the callback.

In your callback function that returns a route, you need to check if this is the answer to the last request.  If so, then your array has all the results and you can then process the array.

Assuming that `originPoints` is an array, you could do it like this:

```
var arrayOfRes = [];
for (var index = 0; index < originPoints.length; ++index) {
    var request = {
        origin:originPoints[index].marker.position,
        destination:destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            var res = {};
            res.length = result.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value;
            res.index = index;
            res.result = result;
            arrayOfRes.push(res);

            // check if all data has arrived
            if (arrayOfRes.length === originPoints.length) {
                // put code here to process arrayOfRes
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Note: javascript does not have the ability to make your code wait for all the requests to be done and then continue - thus you have to use an asynchronous programming style with the flow of code continuing from the callback.

Note: because `directionsService.route` is an asynchronous call, it will call its callback sometime in the future.  In the meantime, you JS will continue to execute.  That means that the code that comes right after this block of code will execute BEFORE the ajax calls have completed and before `arrayOfRes` is populated.  As such, the ONLY place you can safely use the `arrayOfRes` data is in the callback itself or in a function that you call from the callback.